# How to crop and join audio clips in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation

Is there a FOSS software (preferably graphical) to extract a portion of an audio in Ubuntu, and to join multiple clips?

It would be helpful if the software can also playback the portion of the audio while cropping it.

Years ago, I once used Nero Wave editor, and I am looking for something with a similar functionality.

I know that ffmpeg can do it, but I was looking for a graphical frontend.

Comment: Losslesscut from the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: You can do all that in Audacity - except the bit about playback while cropping. You can even open two instances and cut/paste from one instance to another.

Comment: @24601 Losslesscut is good. It is also available as a non-snap version on GitHub. Please write it into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Losslesscut from the Ubuntu Software Centre as a snap.

[image]

It is a utility where portions of audio or video can be extracted and joined together in a graphical interface.

It is also available as an appimage/binary executable from [GitHub](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/releases/tag/v3.32.0) if you prefer.